# Keep getting a sql syntax-error whth this query in joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla, syntax-error

I have a problem with the following query.  It keeps giving me an error 1064 and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
/*storing in the database */
$query = 'INSERT INTO #__comprofiler SET(`cb_googlex`, `cb_googley`) WHERE `user_id`= \''. $userComplete->id . '\'
VALUES ( \''.$mapCor['latitude'].'\', \''.$mapCor['longitude'].'\')';
$_CB_database->setQuery($query);
$_CB_database->loadResult();
```

Comment: maybe you can share the error that you received,

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do an update here is the correct syntax:

```
$query = 'UPDATE __comprofiler 
          SET `cb_googlex` = \''.$mapCor['latitude'].'\',
              `cb_googley` = \''.$mapCor['longitude'].'\'
          WHERE `user_id`= \''. $userComplete->id . '\';';
```

Comment: Getting the same result without the # and this query is happening in a joomla site so i believed that the #__ is standard issue for the prefix of the table

Comment: this is what i'am getting :

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`cb_googlex`, `cb_googley`) WHERE `user_id`= '145' VALUES ( '5.039849', '52.141' at line 1 SQL=INSERT INTO __comprofiler SET(`cb_googlex`, `cb_googley`) WHERE `user_id`= '145' VALUES ( '5.039849', '52.1417635')

Comment: See my update, you were trying to make an update with an insert command

Comment: Oke at first i got the error :Table 'deruiltasnl_dpiart.__comprofiler' doesn't exist SQL=UPDATE __comprofiler SET `cb_googlex` = '5.039849', `cb_googley` = '52.1417635' WHERE `user_id`= '146';

Comment: I have added the # and now is's storing the data But the values are not corect i only see zeros instead of the real values colums are set as float with a lenght of 15,11

Comment: maybe you should remove the quotes around the number

Comment: That does the job super thx lbu i'am new to sql but thanks again